# Disable hyperlink until animation is complete/disable hyperlink on element that has been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple pictures in divs with the class .overlay and when one is clicked the contents of 2 variables fill 2 other elements. There are 2 more things that I need to address, however.

1. I would like all of the .overlay elements to be unclickable until the animation is completed.
2. I would like the .overlay that was clicked to remain unclickable until a different .overlay is clicked.

Code:

```
$('.overlay').on("click",function(){
    var text = $(this).attr("title");
        $('#category').animate({'opacity': 0}, 1000, function () {
        $(this).text(text);
        }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 1000);
    var $clicked = $(this);
        $('#description').animate({'opacity': 0}, 1000, function () {
        $(this).text($clicked.data('text'));
        }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: look up how to use event.preventdefault in jquery, that should help you. (I don't have time to answer fully right now)

Answer (score 1):

You can set a mutex that prevents clicking during animation and is freed upon animation completion:

```
var mutex = false;
$('.overlay').on("click",function() {
    //flag to determine the last clicked overlay
    $(this).data('active', true);
    $('.overlay').not(this).data('active', false);
    if (!mutex && !$(this).data('active')) {
        mutex = true;

        /* snip */
        //animation is complete, so allow clicking all overlay again
        }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 1000, function () { mutex = false; });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('.overlay').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // rest of code
}, false);
```